# How are weights determined in a numerical scheme?

Tags: numerical-methods

A numerical scheme has linear\convex combinations to weight the slopes at different time steps. How are these weights determined? It is through some mathematical techniques or through trial & error?

This [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvxdy.png) has the description and algorithm for the Adams-Bashford-Moulton predictor-corrector method. In the [Algorithm box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpCEZ.png), how the weights $55, 59, 37, ...$ are determined?

Comment: Usually using Taylor methods. Sometimes these can be applied more algebraically, leading to compact algorithms like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473300/please-correct-if-there-a-mistake-on-my-explicit-formula-of-7th-steps-adam-bashf

Comment: Thanks! Just found this Wiki article on the same https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple example of second order [Adams-Bashford scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method#Two-step_Adams%E2%80%93Bashforth) for $y' = f\left( {x,y} \right)$,

\begin{equation} \label{wt1}
{y_{n + 1}} = {y_n} + h\left( {\frac{3}{2}{f_n} - \frac{1}{2}{f_{n - 1}}} \right)
\end{equation}

where $n$ is the grid point, $h$ is the step size and ${f_n} \equiv f\left( {{x_n},{y_n}} \right)$. The co-efficients $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ are called the weights of a numerical scheme.

To derive an explicit scheme of any order, lets assume that $y_{n + 1}$ can be obtained from adding the integral of a [polynomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) to $y_n$, i.e. ${y_{n + 1}} = {y_n} + \int_{{x_n}}^{{x_{n + 1}}} {P\left( x \right)dx} $ where $P\left( x \right)$ is some polynomial.

\begin{equation} \label{wt2}
{y_{n + 1}} = {y_n} + \int_{{x_n}}^{{x_{n + 1}}} {\sum\limits_{i = n}^{n - k} {{L_i}\left( x \right){f_i}} \text{ } dx} 
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation} \label{wt3}
{L_i}\left( x \right) = \mathop {\mathop \prod \limits_{j = n}^{n - k} }\limits_{j \ne i} \frac{{x - {x_j}}}{{{x_i} - {x_j}}}
\end{equation}

here $k + 1$ gives the order of accuracy and ${L_i}\left( x \right)$ are called cardinal functions. The term under the integral is the [Lagrangian polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), $P\left( x \right)$ of order $k$.

For a [multi-step explicit method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method) of order 2 with the information at $x_n$ and $x_{n - 1}$, $y_{n+1}$ becomes,

\begin{equation} \label{wt4}
{y_{n + 1}} = {y_n} + \int_{{x_n}}^{{x_{n + 1}}} {\left[ {{L_n}\left( x \right){f_n} + {L_{n - 1}}\left( x \right){f_{n - 1}}} \right]} \text{ } dx
\end{equation}

By expanding the cardinal functions, we get,

\begin{equation} \label{wt5}
{y_{n + 1}} = {y_n} + {f_n}\int_{{x_n}}^{{x_{n + 1}}} {\frac{{x - {x_n}}}{h} \text{ } dx}  - {f_{n - 1}}\int_{{x_n}}^{{x_{n + 1}}} {\frac{{x - {x_{n - 1}}}}{h} \text{ } dx} 
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation} \label{wt6}
{L_n}\left( x \right) = \frac{{x - {x_n}}}{h}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{wt7}
{L_{n - 1}}\left( x \right) = \frac{{x - {x_{n - 1}}}}{{ - h}}
\end{equation}

Upon integrating, we get,

\begin{equation} \label{wt8}
{y_{n + 1}} = {y_n} + h\left( {\frac{3}{2}{f_n} - \frac{1}{2}{f_{n - 1}}} \right)
\end{equation}

The higher schemes require more algebra but calculated in a similar way as shown in the example above. Furthermore, implicit methods are derived by the same formula but includes $f_{n+1}$ information while approximating the polynomial, $P\left( x \right)$.

More information [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAjel3GLt0A&t=1078s).