# Is any direct Adams Moulton formula or how to related those two formula which i am mention.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, education, matlab, programming

Are those formulas the same? When I am programming for Adams Moulton fourth order methods I use the 2nd formula which I mentioned in the 2nd image. Is it correct?

If correct, please explain me.

[This Formula is Adams Moulton fourth order (I find this on my book)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXq30.jpg)

[This formula is Adams Moulton fourth order (I found this on a website when I searched for a Fortran algorithm)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtNAD.jpg)

Comment: The first is the 4th order A-M formula, the second appears to be some kind of Newton step (possibly incorrect) for the 5th order A-M method. I listed the coefficient arrays in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473300.

Answer (score 0):

The 5th order Adams-Moulton formula is
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{720}\left[\begin{aligned}
 &251·f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})+ 646·f(x_n,y_n)\\ &-264·f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})+ 106·f(x_{n-2},y_{n-2})  \\&-19·f(x_{n-3},y_{n-3}) \end{aligned}\right]
$$
This is an implicit equation for $y_{n+1}$. One could iterate it directly as
$$
y_{n+1}^{[k+1]}=y_n+\frac{h}{720}[
 251·f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}^{[k]})+ R_n],
\\~\\
R_n=\begin{aligned}[t]&646·f(x_n,y_n) -264·f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\\&+ 106·f(x_{n-2},y_{n-2})  -19·f(x_{n-3},y_{n-3})\end{aligned}
$$
or try to accelerate this by capturing the majority of the linear behavior of $f$ close to $(x_n,y_n)$ in some Jacobian $J_n$, to get the linear system
$$
\left(I-h·\frac{251}{720}·J_n\right)y^{[k+1]}_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{720}\Bigl[
 251·\bigl[f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}^{[k]})-J_n·y_{n+1}^{[k]}\bigr]+ R_n\Bigr]
$$
For some special case of $f$ this might result in your second formula.

Comment: Thank you so much.