# Understanding Runge-kutta and Linear multistep method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

In the **Numerical Analysis by Richard L. Burden**, section $5.4$ was told that

The first step in deriving a Runge-Kutta method is to determine values for $a_{1}, \alpha_{1}$, and $\beta_{1}$ with the property that $\color{red}{a_{1} f\left(t+\alpha_{1}, y+\beta_{1}\right)}$ approximates
$$
T^{(2)}(t, y)=f(t, y)+\frac{h}{2} f^{\prime}(t, y)
$$
with error no greater than $O\left(h^{2}\right)$, which is the same as the order of the local truncation error for the Taylor method of order two. And for higher order Runge-kutta methods the term $T^{(3)}(t, y)$ can be approximated with error $O\left(h^{3}\right)$ by an expression of the form
$$
\color{red}{f\left(t+\alpha_{1}, y+\delta_{1} f\left(t+\alpha_{2}, y+\delta_{2} f(t, y)\right)\right)},
$$
involving four parameters, the algebra involved in the determination of $\alpha_{1}, \delta_{1}, \alpha_{2}$, and $\delta_{2}$ is quite involved.

---

$(1)$ I don't understand how they guess the expression like that? [red colored] Is there any logic behind this? Without understanding, it's like memorizing the derivation. 
$(2)$ Another question is from [linear multistep methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method#Families_of_multistep_methods). Is there any way to quickly come up with the coefficient of those methods, like for $3$ step method, the coefficients $\frac{23}{12},-\frac{16}{12}$ and $\frac{5}{12}$. It's hard to memorize and can't derive the whole formula in exam time.

#### Adams–Bashforth methods

[image: image1]

#### Adams–Moulton methods

[image: image2]

Comment: To 1), there was the Euler method, and then some miracle happened. There really was a jump in knowledge of this sort around 1900. Where before there was a poorly understood Runge (1895) method, in 1900-01 Heun/Kutta presented all the lower order methods that are used today, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527302/whats-the-motivation-for-runge-kutta-methods/2527316?r=SearchResults&s=5|14.8178#2527316

Comment: To 2), there is not really a nice memorization formula. However, the coefficients can be systematically computed in a short algorithm, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473300/please-correct-if-there-a-mistake-on-my-explicit-formula-of-7th-steps-adam-bashf/3473602?r=SearchResults&s=1|33.0678#3473602